# Watson Knowledge Studio: how to get the remainder of a sentence using rules?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson

As stated in the object, I'm working with IBM watson knowledge studio and I'm trying to get the remainder of a sentence after a specific term.
I have associated a class with a dictionary to identify the term. This works fine.

But I'm not sure how to say : get all the words until the next punctuation mark.
I've tried with a regex but not to avail.

example :

> It might need to be revised so it **matches** the text that you intended for it to find.

'matches' is my specific word and I'd like to get 'the text that you intended for it to find.'

Any advice? How would you achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there is no way to write such patterns because WKS rule has several limitations about the maximum number of tokens. Please refer to this page.

#### Creating a rule-based annotator

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/wks/wks_rule_annotator_ovw.shtml

> - The maximum number of single token, annotation, or 'any token' group cells that can participate in a pattern is 15 when each cell has a repeat setting of 1 or less.
> - And the maximum number of total tokens allowed in a pattern is 20.
> - the token can repeat up to 5 times

For example, you'd like to write such a rule that:

- starts with TARGET class associated with TARGET dictionary (that includes "matches", and specific terms)
- accompanied by "any token" at "Repeating 0 or more times" with annotation (for example, class "REMAINDER")

However, "the text that you intended" is only annotated with "REMAINDER" in your case.